# How to optimize a fairly straight-forward subquery, TOP increases execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a better solution for the following query, this one takes a few seconds to run and adding a TOP to it increases the execution time.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
DECLARE @firstTerm NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @lastTerm NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @totalKeywords INT;
SET @firstTerm = 'john';
SET @lastTerm = 'doe';
SET @totalKeywords=2;

SELECT 20 AS [Priority], clientid AS ClientId
FROM clients.dbo.ViewClientsByFullname WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE @totalKeywords > 1 AND fullname IN (
 SELECT COALESCE(ParentName + ' ','') + @lastTerm AS Name
 FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
 WHERE Name=@firstTerm OR ParentName=@firstTerm
 UNION
 SELECT COALESCE(Name + ' ','') + @lastTerm AS Name 
 FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
 WHERE ParentName IN (
  SELECT ParentName 
  FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
  WHERE Name=@firstTerm OR ParentName=@firstTerm
  )
 )
```

The query is basically checking a table for a list of alternate names (ex. @firstTerm=Robert then it also gets a list of bob, bobby, rob etc) and then does a search against those alternate names as well.

I was trying to think of a way to do this with an INNER JOIN, but was stumped for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how this would work with explicit joins instead of the `in` statement:

```
SELECT 20 AS [Priority], clientid AS ClientId
FROM clients.dbo.ViewClientsByFullname v WITH (NOLOCK) left outer join
     (SELECT distinct COALESCE(ParentName + ' ','') + @lastTerm AS Name
      FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE Name=@firstTerm OR ParentName=@firstTerm
    ) c1
    on v.fullname = c1.name left outer join
    (select distinct COALESCE(Name + ' ','') + @lastTerm AS Name 
     FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE ParentName IN (SELECT ParentName 
                          FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
                          WHERE Name=@firstTerm OR ParentName=@firstTerm
                         )
    ) c2
    on v.fullname = c2.name
WHERE @totalKeywords > 1 AND (c1.name is not null or c2.name is not null)
```

Comment: Interestingly, using your query took 25 seconds longer than the first. I actually thought it may offer a slight performance gain but it did quite the opposite!

Comment: @MichaelBrown . . . That is rather disappointing.  I suspect that you could make either query much faster by putting the inner queries in a temporary table and building an index.

Answer (score 0):

Try your new query

```
SELECT 20 AS [Priority],clientid AS ClientId
FROM clients.dbo.ViewClientsByFullname WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE @totalKeywords > 1
  AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.DiminuitiveNames WITH (NOLOCK) 
              WHERE Name=@firstTerm OR ParentName=@firstTerm
                AND (COALESCE(ParentName + ' ','') + @lastTerm = fullname
                  OR COALESCE(Name + ' ','') + @lastTerm = fullname)    
              )
```